# Is there any way to add Canvas App into Model Driven App in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven

We have requirement where we need to add a Canvas App into Model Driven Screen Page, but when we are adding that is showing the error below, can any one please help on below mentioned issue:
Any suggestion will be helpful.
[image]

Thanks in Advance